# Python fetch all consecutive odd or even numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Given a list of integers, how can I group together consecutive numbers that share the same parity?

Here is an example input:

```py
[5, 9, 11, 20, 24, 30, 31, 33, 39, 41]
```

And here is an example output:

```
[[5, 9, 11], [20, 24, 30], [31, 33, 39, 41]]
```

Answer (score 0):

a simple loop does the job:

```
test = [5,7,9,11,13,20,22,24,31,33,39,41,43,44,46,50,52]

result = []
res = []
prevalue = None
for v in test:
    if prevalue == None or v == prevalue + 2:
        prevalue = v
        res.append(v)
    else:
        prevalue = v
        result+= [res]
        res = [v]

result+= [res]

print(result)
```

result:

```
[[5, 7, 9, 11, 13], [20, 22, 24], [31, 33], [39, 41, 43], [44, 46], [50, 52]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`itertools.groupby()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to produce the groupings of odd / even numbers:

```py
[list(group) for _, group in groupby(data, lambda x: x % 2 == 0)]
```

This outputs:

```py
[[5, 9, 11], [20, 24, 30], [31, 33, 39, 41]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, what you want to do is track the current list you're looking at and modify it as you go and, when your condition no longer holds true, you save the list and create a new one:

```
results = []
current = [data[0]]
flag = data[0] % 2
for number in data[1:]:
    if number % 2 == flag:
        current.append(number)
    else:
        flag = 1 - flag
        results.append(current)
        current = [number]
results.append(current)
```